# Read the data from Hbase Table using Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, spark-streaming

I am new into Spark and trying to get single member record from Hbase Table using Spark Streaming. Passing a Member ID using local host, 9999 and want to print all the events data for that Member ID. Couldn't find any example for a reference.

Can anyone provide example to read a data from Hbase Table using Spark StreamingContext ?? Reply as soon as possible

Comment: this may help - http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/08/apache-spark-comes-to-apache-hbase-with-hbase-spark-module/

Comment: this may also help - https://www.mapr.com/blog/spark-streaming-hbase

Comment: @Sumit the mapr example is not getting compiled fully. Getting this error "[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project sparkstreamhbaseapp: Could not resolve dependencies for project mapr:sparkstreamhbaseapp:jar:1.0: Failed to collect dependencies for " any fix you have? Are you able to move beyond this point?